# Custom close button in datetimepicker form

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I use datetimepicker in my project, I find out how to change icon of close button by using [option of datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#showclose) but I want close button show up with "close" text inside, not icon. Is it possible? If yes, please tell me how to do it.

This is my JavaScript file:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    useCurrent: false,
    format: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm ZZ",
    locale: "ja",
    sideBySide: true,
    toolbarPlacement: "bottom",
    showClose: true,
    icons: {
      close: "fa fa-check"
    }
  });
});
```