# Custom datetimepicker hover color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

By default, hovering color of table and button in DateTimePicker is grey, how to change it into custom color? I tryed the css code below but nothing happens.

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active:hover{
    background-color: #337ab7; 
    color:#fff;
}
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget button:hover{
    background-color: #337ab7; 
    color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the buttons are not `<button>` elements, so your CSS rule is not matched.

You can use `data-action` attribute to select a button element and set colors as you want.

Here a live example for the close button.

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  useCurrent: false,
  format: "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm ZZ",
  //locale: "ja",
  sideBySide: true,
  toolbarPlacement: "bottom",
  showClose: true,
  icons: {
      close: 'closeText'
  }
});
```

```css
.closeText:before {
    content: "Close";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td a[data-action="close"]>span:hover {
  /* Set her your custom color */
  background-color: #337ab7; 
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <input type='text' class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note that the picker has the [`debug`](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#debug) option that allows you inspect component's HTML to simplyfy style customization.

P.S. I've set up the example starting from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42780486/4131048).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.day:hover,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.hour:hover,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.minute:hover,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.second:hover {

  background-color: #123456; // Your custom color

}
```

PS. Look into the basics of [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).

Comment: thank you but this code only change time value hover color, how to i change button hovering color too?

Comment: What button color? Please add a screenshot or more specific info.